banned after I answered a question, I was a little rude as there was some misinformation, the reason given is that my questions need improvement
I answered a question and was being rude to a mod because they were coming out with misinformation, after this I was able to write questions, 2, 3, 4, 5 days after up to a nearly a week but I kept cancelling, as I ended up figuring my problems out while just writing the questions.
My answer got 5 upvotes (2 people down voted because I straight up told them they make no sense) but the mod wasn't happy and I have had back and forth with him before.
I come back after a 2 weeks and it says I can't ask questions because they need improvement, but this all happened because of an argument with a mod, so why is this being given as a reason?
My most down voted questions are at -3 or -4 but they are exceptions.
Now the reason given would make sense if I had just asked a bad very down voted question then this came about. Or If I had many questions closed for lack of clarity, which I don't

It seems to me that terdon tried to answer your question, which was "it says I can't ask questions because they need improvement" and quoted the most pertinent parts of the FAQ to you so that you would have your answer right here on this page. It also informs you that it was not *"because of an argument with a mod". Aside from that, being rude to other users (moderators included) will lead to being suspended from the site. Some of your previous (now-deleted) comments have crossed that line. Please be nice. Thank you.

As terdon said, you can still (in theory) edit your existing question(s) to improve them -- without moving the goalposts to invalidate the existing answers, so it's not technically true that "it will do no good". The edit could catch the attention of someone who un-downvotes or upvotes the Q. Additionally, the quoted portion says "If you're blocked from asking questions ... you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question" which gives you those opportunities.

and so you just ignored the point about the first quote in Terdon's answer and stuck to the reason given by the algorithm. You really ought to reason for yourself, it would only improve your life, I have nothing to gain from it. I bet you didn't even read the quote. It's wishful thinking that someone will see an edit and be like 'wow I better upvote this' they aren't going to get notifications, even if they did, it's very unlikely they'd upvote.

I deleted my comments as you didn't consider even 1 point from them.

Thanks for coming to Meta, your comment left me very confused since I had no idea what you were talking about. Your account seems to have been hit with one of the automated bans, specifically a question ban. As explained in that link, this isn't something that moderators have any control over whatsoever. These are automated systems, and mods don't even know the details about exactly what triggers them as those have always been secret:

To avoid bypassing the filter, its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this.

So this has nothing to do with any of the mods here, nor with whether or not you were rude. Unfortunately, that also means none of us can actually remove the ban. The only way is what is explained in the link above:

How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot
simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action,
you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the
ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other
ways.
Moderators cannot lift the ban.
Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above, downvotes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban

so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!

Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. As
explained above, negative marks on deleted posts do still count
towards the question ban, and the fact that they are deleted can also
count against you (with the exception of questions that are 30 days or
older when deleted). Deleting your posts does not help to lift the
ban. Only fixing does! You can see a
list
of your own deleted questions and answers.
[...]
If you're blocked from asking questions and are unable to improve your existing questions (or your existing questions are all deleted), you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question. Your block will still remain once that question is posted, but a single positively-received question could be enough to lift you out of the block. (This does not apply to answer bans.)
If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

So you need to edit your existing questions to improve them. I realize this isn't easy, especially since you don't know the exact thresholds you need to hit. I, personally, am not a huge fan of this particular aspect of the SE system because while it does a great job of dealing with trolls, it is quite confusing for folks like you who do want to try and improve. That's just the way it is though.
In the following mini-analysis, I am including deleted questions as well since:

Are deleted posts taken into account too?
If a post was poorly received (downvoted or closed), those negative
marks will continue to count against your account even if the post
is deleted! Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting
them.
Additionally, for question bans, the fact that a question is deleted
counts against you, if others have invested time into answering or
moderating the question. (This does not apply to questions that are
30 days or older when
deleted,
though any negative marks on those questions can still count against
you.)

Now, let's look at some numbers. You have posted a total of 51 questions, deleted or not. They have an average score of -0.08, a median of 0, a minimum of -4 and a maximum of 4. 39 of them, ~76%, have a score of 0 or less and only 12, ~24%, have a positive score.
That... isn't a great track record. So, try and post some good answers. Even better, try and go back to your negatively voted questions and see if you can improve them. Perhaps some people have left comments with suggestions. Try following their advice. Remember that any edited posts are automatically bumped to the front page so people will see them again. If you just improve some of your existing posts, the ban can be lifted.

As an aside, do try to avoid throwing politically laden terms like "misinformation" around for no reason. I believe you are referring to a conversation between you and another user under that user's answer. Nobody was trying to mislead anyone for any sort of nefarious agenda there. If you think someone was wrong, say so. In the unlikely event you think someone is purposefully lying for some obscure reason, then say that. But please avoid the gratuitous use of buzzwords like "misinformation". They distract from the core, technical subjects this site is about. 
